# Safely resetting a mysql table without deleting the data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning on using a local `MySQL` db as a 'data cache' to reduce the amount of writes to a distributed `NoSQL` database.

I want to 'dequeue' the `MySQL` tables *at least* every hour (not that that's relevant.) So basically, I'm looking for a (hopefull fast, ) safe way to have the dequeue script/application 'fetch' all the data and then reset (truncate?) the tables.

And here's the kicker; if it's realistic, I want the scripts that are writing to said `MySQL` db to keep functioning as normal. I'm using `MyISAM` tables, and I think an important detail is that I use the following type of query *a lot*: `INSERT INTO XX (YY, ZZ) VALUES (3, 5) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE YY = YY + 3, ZZ = ZZ + 5;` If it is at all important, I'm fairly sure `MyISAM` tables get locked during such a query.

I'm pretty sure (looks like I'm not certain on anything) that if I was to simply `truncate` all tables, the writer-scripts would just keep on truckin' but I want to move/use the data rather than get rid of it.

Comment: Don't `TRUNCATE`, but just `DELETE` rows as you add them in your `NoSQL`. Why `MyISAM` BTW? If you'd use `InnoDB`, you could just _access_ it like a `NoSQL` database....

Comment: @Wrikken I tried `InnoDB`, but it's loads and loads slower on writes than `MyISAM` is, and while there's certainly room for improvement, it'll never be as fast as `MyISAM`. The problem with iterating over live data and using `DELETE` is the counter may have been incremented by the writer script since the dequeue script read it, and table-wide locks are of course a big nono performance wise. For that matter, any form of locking is.

Comment: Yes, the locking is why I hate `MyISAM` (entire pages, tssk, InnoDB just locks 1 record). And of course not being able to do safe transaction, like we're running into now... To get the full picture: what is this counter you speak of: is that data _in_ the table, as in, you're 'dequeuing' while there's still a possibility data is being written to the records? How are you resolving this application wise: if it'd be the truncate option, you'd have stored the incremented counter in NoSQL, but a new record is created in the 'queue' table?

Comment: @Wrikken Look at the query in my question; that's what I meant when I said counter. Yes, it's possible the dequeue script reads that value, the write script increments it before the deq. script gets a chance to delete it, and the deq. script then deletes the missed increment along with the rest of the row. If there's no better option, I can of course use a lock file so the write scripts are only briefly put on hold when the dequeue script wants to do work. Writers process data in 70mb chunks so they wouldn't have to lock that often & dequeue can wait. But I'd rather use a less complex method.

Comment: Actually that'd be a pretty crappy solution because writers would have to wait for each other as well as the dequeue script thus slowing down the whole thing significantly ;/ 3 writers could be idling at the lock while 2 are still working on their 70mb chunk, thus wasting 3 writers' processing power until the other 2 are done.

Comment: Hm, a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` does not really work with MyISAM, so no go there.. What _is_ pretty atomic is a `RENAME` (which can't be done while holding locks): stop the processes, `RENAME` the original table to another tablename, `CREATE` a new empty table, start the processes, and merrily go on your way entering the data no other process will use from your renamed table? (Possibly test whether _first_ creating the new table by another name & doing 2 `RENAME`'s in a row is faster). If you can't stop the inserting... there's still a chance your processes hit a non-existing table error.

Comment: `stop the processes` is a significant issue, because it means I either have to start keeping track on the writer's progress in the 70mb chunk   (waste of IO) or I'd have to do a clean close and make all writers wait on each other, (waste of processing power because nothing is happening while they wait)

Comment: Hm, if your application can detect a failed insert and just do a microsecond sleep & retry the last insert, it might work. Not pretty, but the reason `MyISAM` is faster is _because_ it's not that safe in transactions.

Comment: I could definitely work with that, if I understand you correctly. You're suggesting I simply do the rename, and make the writer recover from the resulting failed insert by looping until the table exists again? Any chance on losing an increment that way?

Comment: Argh, silly me, we can do this: `RENAME TABLE current_table TO old_table, new_table TO current_table;` in 1 statement. Even less change of interruption by `INSERT`'s in between. You'll _probably_ not lose any increment if the sleep & retry is executed correctly. As long as an `INSERT` is active on the table it won't be renamed, and just wait in the queue for its turn.

Comment: I hesitate to ask, because it just sounds too good to be true, but would that be atomic (respecting the lock occurring during increment?) I mean how can it lock a table that doesn't really exist anymore? ^^

Comment: Yes, it seems you don't even need the sleep [_"The rename operation is done atomically, which means that no other session can access any of the tables while the rename is running."_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rename-table.html). The example mentioned there is _exactly_ what we're trying to do ;)

Comment: I'm gonna give it a go then, thanks!